# ipad device screen orientation is not correctly when it is rotate

Tags: ios, xamarin, orientation, xamarin.forms, landscape-portrait

I'm working on this iPhone app, whose orientation works all fine except first screen. The first screen also works fine if the device is in portrait orientation, but not for landscape orientation.

Interestingly, if I rotate device at the first screen, it also adjust well.

The problem looks to me is that the app always assumes the device is in portrait orientation, so the first screen is always shown in portrait orientation even if the device is in landscape orientation.

what can i do to solve this.

Thanks, Please help Me

Answer (score 0):

This nugget package may help you:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Forms.DeviceOrientation/

So can check which orientation the device is.